# How to ACCURATELY Measure ACTUAL BANDWIDTH Performance of a Full-Fibre FTTP Broadband Connection

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth, broadband, fiber

I have an 80MB Down / 20MB UP FTTP broadband connection.

I did a an Internet Speed Test and this reported a performance of 43 MB. Review of bandwidth and CPU usage on the router didn't account for the gap in contracted speed vs actual speed.

How can I test isolating the FTTP connection from other potential issues affecting bandwidth usage and get as "clean" a connection as possible?

Answer (score 2):

## Intro:

I just bumped into this with my FTTP Full-Fibre connection and OpenReach couldn't figure it out, so felt it was worth documenting for others. Not many with FTTP now, but I expect that to change soon with all WFH these days.

A line-test revealed there were no problems, however, neither could a review of the SNMP bandwidth monitoring & CPU usage account for the gap in performance that these Internet Speed Tests-using 5G WiFi which supports 1.3 Gbps connectivity- were reporting which was very material in size.

## Solution:

Although you could connect your computer directly to the Router via an Ethernet cable, this would allow the service provider to say that the reduced bandwidth is due to the router and enable them to blow you off.

So to exclude the router itself as a potential cause of the bandwidth issue, the OpenReach Engineer wanted to test the performance of the connection directly from the ONT.

The following procedure was accomplished using a MacBook Pro 2018 which has only USB-C ports. Windows users will therefore have to tweak the following instructions accordingly:

0. **ENSURE THE COMPUTER THAT YOU'RE TESTING WITH HAS THE FIREWALL UP AND ALLOWING ONLY *RELATED/ESTABLISHED* CONNECTIONS IN BEFORE CONTINUING** You'll be connecting your computer to the Internet on a publicly routable IP address. Generally not something one wants to do ;-)
1. Unplug the Router's Ethernet cable from the ONT.
2. Plug the USB-C Ethernet Adapter into the Macbook's USB-C port.
3. Connect an Ethernet Cable from your computer's Ethernet Adaptor to the ONT.
4. ***System*** > ***Preferences*** > ***Networking***: Next, manually configure the Router's GW Public IP address on the "*Belkin USB-C LAN*" Ethernet adaptor's interface. Since this is a Point-to-Point link, set the subnet mask for it to `255.255.255.252`
5. Click the "**+**" at bottom of the dialogue box, choose "***PPPoE***" and enter the Broadband provider's auth credentials for your FTTP connection. Once enabled you should get feedback that it is configured correctly
6. Start a web browser, run your bandwidth speed tests and make whatever screen-grabs you require.
7. Immediately unplug your computer from the ONT connection.
8. Plug the router's Ethernet cable back into the ONT.

## Conclusion:

This is a simple way to isolate issues with bandwidth and get as clean a connection as possible.

It's advisable to run several Internet Speed Tests while connected to the ONT for comparative purposes, to ensure the results are reproducible.

Comment: On an FTTC connection I once had the engineers back so many times they eventually sent a 'proper' engineer, who apologised for not being used to customer-facing [which didn't bother me in the slightest, he was more polite than the others anyway;) He then muttered for 15 mins about how the regular guys were under-trained & couldn't find their ar$e with both hands and a map, re-configged the physical connection [different attenuator] & box .. & I haven't looked back since. [He also gave me his own phone number & another to get hold of 'scotland/ireland' instead of 'india' if I needed more help.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I had the same exact thing: OpenReach subcontracted out to Kelly's here in the UK. The Kelly's folks are really Fibre installers and not network engineers. The can connect the Fibre to the ONT, but that's where their skills end. They cannot even validate the ONT is correct: they have almost zero diagnostic tools. OpenReach was Blaming the ISP and vice versa. Took 5 days to get my FTTP connection installed and were I not a network engineer, it still wouldn't be installed. I had the same nightmare experience.  Hopefully answers like this will give power to customers!